# how to Center the navigation bar

Tags: html, css

Hi I am working on the following website for a class, it is suppose to be very simple, nothing crazy. I am trying to get the navigation bar in the middle and have equal spacing in between using CSS. here is the link for it

http://bit.ly/16icBEi

Comment: link doesn't seem to be correct. please check it

Comment: First, you should place all those <a> tags in <li> tags seeing as you wrap them in a <ul> tag. Not sure what that <id> tag is all about.

Comment: its centered now but it hat bullet points

Comment: to remove bullet point add .menu-item {list-style: none;} on your css part

Comment: The "Too Localized" close reason is because you have not included any code here, but instead a link to your website. That makes this question of no use to future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `text-align:center` for the `#navigation`, and use `display:inline` for list styling

```
#navigation{
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
}
#navigation li{
    display:inline;
    background:#333;
    padding:5px 10px;
}
```

Have a look at here http://jsfiddle.net/qiqiabaziz/uJ5Tw

You can remove any unused id or class name for`<ul id="navigation" class="menu-item">`, just so you know, the class name is reusable but the id is not. Pick the one which suits you well.

Comment: glad it solved your problems :)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comment, your html is invalid.
Changing it to something like this would fix that:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul id="navigation" class="menu-item">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="sitemap.html">Site Map</a></id="menu></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As for centering it, your menu class is width 100%. Your ul is also given a menu class for some reason, but no evident one. So I suggest giving the ul its own class and defining a width for it:

```
.menu-item{
    width:400px; /* or whatever your actual width is */
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

margin: 0 auto will work if the element has a width. It will do nothing if it doesn't. So in other words, give your menu a width, then apply a left and right auto margin to that element. `0 auto` is shorthand for top and bottom 0px, left and right auto.

Answer (score 1):

You can `align` to set the alignment for the division `<div></div>`;

Example :-

```
<div align="ceneter">
       //Your Navigator here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your navigation HTML markup is not valid. `ul` elements can only contains `li` elements. But in your markup there is no `li` elements inside `ul`. You are using `Id` tag which is not even a valid tag. So change your markup something like this

```
<ul id="navigation" class="menu item">
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="sitemap.html">Site Map</a></li>
</ul>
```

and change your `menu` class with following

```
.menu {
z-index: 9999;
/*width: 100%;*/ remove it
margin:0px auto;
}
```

Comment: I got it to be center but now its a stack bullet points.

Comment: @codeeeeeNOT if you want to remove bullets then simply use `list-style:none` with `ul` class.

Answer (score 0):

make some change to css :

```
.menu {
z-index: 9999;
width: 364px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's quite dirty but it works... on you `<div class="menu">` you add attribute `align`
so it will look like this:

```
<div align="center" class="menu">
```

Then now it will center your menu..